# Example for infinite product topology

Tags: general-topology, infinite-product

> (Comparison of the box and product topologies). The box topology on
>   $\prod X_\alpha$ has as basis all sets of the form $\prod U_\alpha$,
>   where $U_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$. The product
>   topology on $\prod X_\alpha$ has as basis all sets of the form $\prod
> > U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$
>   and $U_\alpha$ equals $X_\alpha$ except for finitely many values of
>   $\alpha$.

Munkres' *Topology* doesn't provide some examples to illustrate the difference between box topology and product topology, so can someone give some examples to help us understand these two concepts? Is $\prod X_\alpha$ a basis element of the product topology?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871610/why-are-box-topology-and-product-topology-different-on-infinite-products-of-topo

Answer (score 0):

$\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ is certainly open, as all but zero (zero is finite) sets in the product equal $X_\alpha$.