# basis for product topology

Tags: general-topology

In the Topology by James R Munkres, the definition for basis of a product topology is given as
"Collection of all sets of the form
$$\prod_{i\epsilon I}^{ }{B_i}$$
where Bi are subset for finitely many i's and Bi equals entire set Xi for remaining indices." Can anyone clarify why this distinction for some i's. Why entire sets than open subsets for remaining i's in defining basis for product topology.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Munkres calls the topology with basis the arbitray products of open sets the *box topology*.

Comment: The product topology has this crucial property: a map $Y\mapsto\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is continuous iff each map $Y\to X_i$ got by composing it with the projection to $X_i$ is continuous.

Comment: The product topology also has the useful property that a sequence of elements $x_n \in \prod_{i\in I} X_i$ converges to $x \in \prod_{i\in I} X_i$ if and only if $x_n \to x$ pointwise, i.e. $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n(i) = x(i)$ for each $i \in I$.  (And if you're familiar with nets, the obvious corresponding condition happens for convergence of nets in general.)  In the box topology, on the other hand, this condition is not sufficient to make a convergent sequence.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176647/defining-product-topology#comment6539511_3176647) may help. The product topology is the smallest topology that makes the projection maps continuous.

Comment: Is the box topology envisaged as a subspace of product topology?

Comment: No, it's an alternative topology to put on the set $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$.